# What do you call words that are typed the same way on a phone keypad?

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography, telephone

Words that are pronounced the same are *homophones*.
Words that are spelled the same are *homonyms*.
What do you call words that are typed the same way on a telephone keypad? (you have to watch out for them when typing text messages!)

Example: *good* and *home* are both typed as 4663 using Predictive Text.

Comment: I so want to say the answer is "homophone".

Comment: Hmmm, can we make something with *homo/numero/nota*?

Comment: _Book_ / _Cool_ is the [classic example](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=book&defid=910471).

Comment: Post MετάEd's *numeronym* I'd propose *padonym* after (numeric- /key-) 'pad' of a generic device that follows the standard pattern of arranging numeric keys.

Answer (score 7):

A *numeronym* is a word which is sometimes spelled using numerals.[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym) It was originally a term for a telephone number having an alphanumeric meaning. Here are some illustrative examples of different types of numeronym.

- *800-DIGITAL* (344-4825, once the toll-free number for the legendary computer company)[²](http://www.google.com/search?q=800-344-4825) – A telephone number having an alphanumeric meaning: the original use of *numeronym* was for such numbers.
- *4#26#4663*, pronounced *I AM HOME* (or *I AM GONE*) – Using symbols on a telephone keypad to spell words. Notice how this example shows that predictive texting technology can lead to ambiguities. Slang terms are also developing for such ambiguities, such as “textonym” and “tynonym”.[³](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_text)
- *i18n*, pronounced *internationalization* – Abbreviation using numerals to represent the *number* of omitted letters.[⁴](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)
- *K9*, pronounced *canine* – Abbreviation using numerals to represent the *sound* of omitted letters.[⁵](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/K9)
- *l33t*, pronounced *leet* (slang for *elite*) – Using numerals which resemble letters they replace.[⁶](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/l33t)
- *07734*, pronounced *hello* – Using numerals which (upside down) resemble letters they replace, also known as *beghilos* or “calculator spelling”.[⁷](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculator_spelling)
- *G8* and *Y2K*, pronounced *gee-eight* and *wye-two-kay* – Words originally coined using numerals.[⁸](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym)

Comment: *Numeronym* does appear to be the word describing 3444825=digital. So *ambiguous numeronym* can be used for 4663.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, or in the right situation you could use one of the slang terms I mentioned.

Comment: While we're on the subject of numeronyms, yet another kind of numeronymic ambiguity can happen with words containing Q or Z, which some keypads put under 1, while others put Q & Z under 7 & 9, respectively. (Evidently, it depends on which [standard](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/umaix/v4r2m0/topic/com.ibm.umaix.admin.doc/dtisokey.gif) is used.)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, it ought to be *phonememe*...

;-)

Answer (score -1):

I just had an idea: *homonum*. Sounds like slang (and is likely to be immediately understood due to its similarity to *homonym*) but actually makes sense (unlike *textonym* or *padonym*).

Comment: Are neologisms allowed?

Comment: I love a good neologism but I think the OP was looking for an established term.